# devexpress gridview selected item display in details

Tags: gridview, devexpress

please tell me how to get the selected cells of a gridview ( devexpress) because i want to display an image in panel when i click on an item Like outlook inspired app
[exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQ9tb.png)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method is to bind your GridControl and your detail items to the same data source (for instance, with a [BindingSource component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource(v=vs.110).aspx)). This will keep the GridControl and details panel synchronized.

To easily generate the details panel, try using the [DevExpress DataLayoutControl](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument4921). Set both the GridControl's DataSource and DataLayoutControl's DataSource properties to the BindingSource component, and set the BindingSource.DataSource property to your actual data source (such as a DataTable or IList).

Comment: This is a perfect answer, and it requires no hand-written code

Comment: But it could not be applied

Comment: Can you describe what steps you performed? Did you use a DataLayoutControl and bind it to the same data source as the GridControl? Are the EditValue properties for the various controls on the edit form bound to properties within the data source?

Comment: I've created a Gridcontrol and create a datalayoutcontrol But I did not know how to set both to the same bindingsource ,

Comment: I want a simple explanation of the steps

Comment: Each of those controls has a DataSource property. Set this property to a compatible data source; in your case, something that implements IEnumerable. It may be a DataTable, a List<T>, a BindingList<T> etc...